# Inverted ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, android-cursor

Is there an easy way to display a ListView in reverse order? I am trying to create a conversation-based app, and would like the most recent entries to be at the bottom of the ListView. I am aware of transcriptMode and stackFromBottom, however my problem is the order of the data.

Say I have 100 conversation items, and want to display items 80-100, with 100 being the most recent conversation item. I would like to show 80-100, which implies an ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 20 in my query, which forces the items to be sorted 100 to 80, the opposite of what I need. I currently have some nasty inner query code, but feel like there should be a simpler solution based on reversing the cursor or simply inverting the ListView.

Comment: Not sure if it would work but you could simply query for all items, create an array of the last 20 in the `Cursor` that's returned and then create a `MatrixCursor` from the array and use that for the `ListView`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside the **`baseAdapter`**, for the **`getView()`** method , instead of getting the item in the data in index "position" , use the opposite , meaning : numberOfItems minus the position .

as for showing the number of items , that's also inside the baseAdapter : set the value returned by `getCount()` to be the one you wish it to be (20 in your example,though 80-100 implies that it should be 21 ) .

btw, it seems you are a starter in the case of listView . may i suggest watching this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

also check the api-demos provided by the sdk manager . they have plenty of examples there.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best way to go. I was considering subclassing Cursor to create a ReverseCursor, and also considering altering ListView, but the piece between them is the clear choice. I had just watch Romain's 2009 I/O talk on Android performance which hinted in this direction, thanks for the pointer to the ListView talk.

Answer (score 10):

Use this **getItem** Method inside your Adapter for **reverse order:**

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
   return super.getItem(super.getCount() - position - 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell how to override getItem() method in adapter?

Comment: But it shows a message that @Override is not allowed here. I'm trying to override inside onCreate method

Answer (score 1):

This code is worked for me when pulling data from database.

```
cs.moveToPosition(super.getCount() - position - 1); //cs is Cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Query for records using BETWEEN keyword seems like the easiest solution to me.

Comment: Thanks, BETWEEN is helpful but doesn't quite work for me, since I don't want to add a query to find where the last piece of data is.