# Android - Reverse listview as message display

Tags: android, listview, reverse

I've got a little question for my Android App.
I searched for a long time but found nothing about my problem.

*Scenario* : I've to display a **revert listview** (as Facebook Messenger).
And when the user scrolls to the top, load more messages.

*Problem* : After `notifiyDataAsChanged()` call, the scroll is not the same!
I want to conserve exactly the same position as before loading.

I tried that code :

```
// save index and top position
int index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition()+result.size();
View v = list.getChildAt(index);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// ...
// restore
list.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

But the scroll is not **exactly** the same after loading.

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you should look into using [TranscriptMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode) and [StackFromBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:stackFromBottom) with your listview:

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

By setting the transcript mode to normal it will scroll to the bottom only if the last item was already in view. That way your users can view the previous list view items without interruption when you call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't understand your post. If I am on the item n°32, after notifydatasetchanged, I want to be on item n°32 again ! But now, when this method is called, I'm not on this item...

Comment: This answer is misleading. `stackFromBottom` moves (stacks) the objects to the bottom, it does not create reverse order. The objects are still added from the bottom which is not what @FlorianMacLanglade asked (I'm searching for the same solution as well).

Comment: @Diolor is right.  `stackfromBottom` is just part of what you want.  The other part is the reverse order which is answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941317/inverted-listview-in-android

Comment: Collections.reverse(item); 
would this be helpful ? it just reverses your list collection, hence showing last item at the top of the list.

Answer (score 7):

do like this:

```
Collections.reverse(YourList); // ADD THIS LINE TO REVERSE ORDER!
YourList.notifyDataSetChanged;
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by using the same code as you included but I update the index variable by the number of items I add to the adapter before restoring the position. Seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin is more easy just

```
 myList.reverse()
```