# How to display ListView in Reverse Order (Latest First on Top)?

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview

I want to display the newly added data on top in ListView. 
But it's getting added to the bottom.

I have tried changing `ASC` to `DESC` but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+COL1+ " PRIMARY KEY DESC,"  + COL2 +" text not null );";

        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        //if data as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }


    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Reverse listview as message display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318034/android-reverse-listview-as-message-display)

Comment: when you take the data from SQL add in your SQL statement "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "' ORDER BY COL1 DESC"

Comment: @sausagerus not working

Comment: @user10851894 , did you refresh your list after insert?

Comment: @sausagerus Yes. I did.

Comment: @user10851894 Once you got the data from db use `Collections.reverse(OBTAINED_LIST_FROM_DB);`

Comment: @user10851894 , show your SQL String with desc, or save your data into ArrayList and sort it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Collections.reverse(OBTAINED_LIST_FROM_DB);
```

For more Info : [Collection.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))