# Reverse ParseQueryAdapter ItemList

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, chat

I'm new on both Parse and Android development, and currently developing a chat feature that powered by `ParseQueryAdapter` on Android. The problem is I want the UX like any other chat app: latest message on the bottom and 'load more' button on top, and I couldn't get the result I want.

I tried `orderByAscending("updatedAt")` on my query and the result is seems right: item list ordered from older to newer (top to bottom). Problem appears when max item (25 items) is reached and 'load more' button appears. 'load more' button put on the bottom of the `ListView` and the top message is still the first message delivered.

Now I start to think to order my query `orderByDescending("updatedAt")` back and modify `ParseQueryAdapter`'s `getItem` method so items will be ordered reversely.
I tried to subclass `ParseQueryAdapter`'s `getItem` into:

```
@Override
public ParseObject getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}
```

I get it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941317/inverted-listview-in-android) since `ParseQueryAdapter` is based on `BaseAdapter`.

And sadly it returns `NullPointerException` when getting object's `getParseUser` on my ParseQueryAdapter subclass as below:

```
public class ChatContentCustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public ChatContentCustomAdapter(Context context, final String roomId){ ... }

    public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (object.getParseUser("sender") == cUser) {          
            //populating layout
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be way too much hassle for you to achieve what you really want using the ParseQueryAdapter. I would recommend that fetch the object from Parse and implement a custom BaseAdapter to plugin to your ListView.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I switch my Adapter to BaseAdapter and everything works well.