# Inverting the whole list in a listView

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Any possible way to invert a complete listView items by an Imagebutton click.
I have a `ListView` which displays a list in sequence `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10`. What I want is that when an `ImageButton` is clicked, the list should display its objects in the form of `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1`.

**Example**- 
London
 Newyork
 Boston
 New Jersey
 **In the form of** 
New Jersey
Boston
Newyork
London

**MainActivity.java**

```
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        employees = db.getEmployees(); 
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                employees,
                new String[] {"Name"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});    
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV2);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**MyDatabase.java**

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "plethora.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public Cursor getEmployees() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"2 _id", "Name"};
        String sqlTables = "DelhiBus";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverted ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941317/inverted-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have you do is reverse the arraylist that is populating your listview using

```
Collections.reverse(aList);
```

Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.reverse(mArrayList);` and the notify your `Adapter` so it will be reversed.

Comment: add your logcat please

Comment: I've added logcat. Thank you

Comment: you are inversing the `listView` you need to inverse the `ArrayList`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the code. I've added it. Thank you for any help.